How do I query an API that has a 1000 row restriction in R?
I am trying to query data from the CDC that has >1,000,000 rows of data. I have 2 potential API endpoints I can use, one in CSV and the other in JSON format:
https://data.cdc.gov/resource/jr58-6ysp.json
https://data.cdc.gov/resource/jr58-6ysp.csv
What I need to be able to do is query this data where usa_or_hhsregion == "9". I have looked at other API-related questions and cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly. Here is what I have tried.

Without attempting any query.

res <- GET("https://data.cdc.gov/resource/jr58-6ysp.json")
test <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content))

This produces a data frame of 1000 rows, of which usa_or_hhsregion == "1". I read on the CDC's site they restrict their API to 1000 rows but also read that you are able to expand that restriction (to which I could not find out how).

Attempting to query.

res <- GET("https://data.cdc.gov/resource/jr58-6ysp.json", query = usa_or_hhsregion == "9")

to which I get...
Error: object 'usa_or_hhsregion' not found

I have no preference on which API to use, as long as I am able to obtain all the data for region 9, then any method/API works.

Use httr::GET("https://data.cdc.gov/resource/jr58-6ysp.json", query = "usa_or_hhsregion=9").

This site explains how to page through the Socrata API using the offset keyword.

Appreciate the help.

Since the Data.CDC.gov API is powered by Socrata, you can use the RSocrata package to query the API. Since the SODA API is Version 2.1, according to the documentation, you can use the $limit= parameter to set any upper limit you'd like. At the time of writing this, the API has a total of 173,480 records for HHS Region 9. So you could, for instance, run the following query:
library(RSocrata)

df <- read.socrata(
  url = paste0(
    "https://data.cdc.gov/resource/jr58-6ysp.json",
    "?usa_or_hhsregion=9",
    "&$limit=1753000"
  )
)

